# What does the parameters of trend(window) and season(window) mean in STL decomposition?

Tags: r

I plotted a graph using the STL model and the `autoplot` function. However, I don't understand the meaning of parameters `trend(window)` and `season(window)`. When I type `?trend` and `?season`, R indicates that there is no documentation.

Can anyone help me, please?

The data:

```r
library(fpp3)
us_retail_employment <- us_employment %>%
  filter(year(Month) >= 1990, Title == "Retail Trade") %>%
  select(-Series_ID)

head(us_retail_employment)
Month       Title           Employed
1990 Jan    Retail Trade    13255.8
1990 Feb    Retail Trade    12966.3
1990 Mar    Retail Trade    12938.2
1990 Apr    Retail Trade    13012.3
1990 May    Retail Trade    13108.3
1990 Jun    Retail Trade    13182.8
```

The code:

```r
us_retail_employment %>%
model(STL(Employed ~ trend(window = 16) + season(window = "periodic"), 
      robust = TRUE)) %>%
  components() %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

Comment: There's some good explanation of STL decomposition at the FPP3 book - you'll probably find this the most help: https://otexts.com/fpp3/stl.html

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

`trend` and `season` do not have their own documentation, but rather are described in `?STL`.

For `season(window)`:

> The span (in lags) of the loess window, which should be odd. If the window is set to "periodic" or Inf, the seasonal pattern will be fixed. The window size should be odd and at least 7, according to Cleveland et al.

For `trend(window)`:

> The span (in lags) of the loess window, which should be odd. If NULL, the default, nextodd(ceiling((1.5*period) / (1-(1.5/s.window)))), is taken.

In other words, when we run the STL, we decompose the pattern into a trend, a seasonal pattern, and a remainder. The `window` parameters determine the number of datapoints that the Loess regression considers at each point. Higher values means that it will consider more data points, and hence it will be smoother.

Note that if you specify a number, it should be odd, not even.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I jsut can't understand why we decompose the pattern and adjust the parameters of window in order to become more smoother?

Comment: Well, say you set `trend(windows = 3)`. Assume that you're trying to find some underlying trend. You'll see that the decomposition is near perfect, the remainder (bottom plot) is pretty much 0 for the whole plot. However, the trend (2nd plot) basically follows the employment data very closely. This trend is likely specific for this dataset only; it doesn't look like the true underlying trend. You can make it more robust by setting the window wider (i.e. using more datapoints at each point). Depending on your hypothesis, this may better match reality.